# "Anyone has" vs "Anyone have"

Tags: tense, verbs, indefinite-pronouns

> 1. Anyone **has** xxx's mobile number?
> 2. Anyone **have** xxx's mobile number?

Which one is correct?  Is *anyone* singular or plural?

Comment: The complete sentence is "**Does** anyone have xxx's mobile number?"  But in informal conversation you can omit that first word, and we understand that it's there anyway.  That's why it's *have* and not *has*.

Comment: @snailboat - You can expound on that in an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

Quick Answer: "Anyone" is plural and the second option is correct.

Further discussion:

English speakers often omit words when speaking if the words are unnecessary.

> Have you seen my puppy?

might very easily become

> Seen my puppy?

This practice is more common when speakers know each other well. Often the advantage of quick communication is prioritized over correct grammar. Even so, confusion sometimes results and the speaker might have to say the full sentence anyway.

When writing, it is good practice to keep your sentences grammatical. You don't know the reader well, and can't be certain they will understand the sentence when you omit words. In the example given, as snailboat mentions in the comments,  the "Does" is omitted.